# How to remove the "services" in front of micro services

Tags: jhipster, spring-cloud-gateway

I use jhipster to generate UAA and gateway, but when I access their API interfaces through the gateway, it's like this: “http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080/services/uaa/api/account ”, I want to remove the word "services", what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at how to write a custom `RouteLocator` in Spring Cloud Gateway doc and you may have also to modify `GatewayResource` and of course frontend code.

Also, you must understand that gateway routing should be determined on something in the incoming request or it will not work for resources which have same path in all services like swagger-ui JSON spec.